# How to make TextInputLayout NOT fill the background when error gets set?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting the following. When the error is set, I don't want the box to be filled in red. I am new to using TextInputLayout. How do I fix this?

[image]

I have the following

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til_confirm_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/textBoxBottomGap"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/leftRightMargin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/leftRightMargin"
        app:hintEnabled="false">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/confirm_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:hint="Confirm Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

`@drawable/rounded_edittext` is referencing the following.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="15dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
        android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#999999" />
</shape>
```

I have the following in Activity:

```
    if (!newPlainPssd.equals(confirmPlainPssd)) {
        etConfirmPassword.requestFocus(); //references editText
        tilConfirmPassword.setError("Passwords don't match"); //references TextInputLayout
        return;
    }
```

Comment: share your java code where you are setting error to your textinput layout

Comment: I just shared it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    if (!newPlainPssd.equals(confirmPlainPssd)) {
            etConfirmPassword.requestFocus(); //references editText
            tilConfirmPassword.setError("Passwords don't match"); //references TextInputLayout
             text.setError("Nilesh");
                editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_edittext);
                    }
                }, 50);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I wish I could post the screenshot in comments. Anyways, let me try to explain. The background coloring problem is now solved, but the error message is now part of the text area. It enlarges the text box borders and fits in. Also, a line appears below "Confirm Password" and below that is the error.

Comment: update your question with new problem because i have tested it in my device and its working fine @AayushKarki  please againg check updated ans

Comment: @AayushKarki happy to help you

Answer (score 0):

the soliton is change

```
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
```

to

```
  <solid android:color="@color/transparent"/>
```